# How to make a button give different results everytime when user tap it?

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have a button and I want it to change the text that I positioned above the button to something random everytime the user press it. How can I do it?

I want to look something like this:

```
"Hello"
**press**
"Why did you press?"
**press**
"Don't do that again, or..."
**press**
"You just did!"
```

Here is the code of the button and the text.

```
dontPressButton.setOnClickListener(
            //Sets the button to wait for the press
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View V) {
                    //Selects the text field to be changed
                    TextView textChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textChange);
                    //Changes the text
                    textChange.setText(string.textChange2);
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: make a list of strings containing different responses. and create a random number from 0 to length of this list you made earlier. every time the buttom is pressed a new random number is generated within those limits and you can select the string corresponding to that number in list and display it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magical way to have it randomly change the text, you have to program it to do that. You are going to have to create an array of responses and then in the button's code, tell it to cycle through those responses. So for example:

```
private String[] responseArray = {"Hello", "Why did you press?", "Don't do that Again", "You Just did!" }
private int numTimesPressed = 0  
dontPressButton.setOnClickListener(
            //Sets the button to wait for the press
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View V) {
                    //Selects the text field to be changed
                    TextView textChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textChange);
                    //Changes the text
                    //note this line will cause an error if there is not enough values in the array. You would have to write a catch for this
                    textChange.setText(responseArray[numTimesPressed++]);
                    //if you want random, you'll have to change the array index you are accessing to random value between the array's bounds
                }
            }
);
```

Comment: Thanks fot the answer. But, I am now receiveing an error about final (I already searched and now I know what is). Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to solve it.  I did the same basic code as you showed, just changed the 'numTimesPressed++' to 'numTimesPressed' and added a line below with the 'numTimesPressed++'. I tried with your example, didn't work.

Comment: @meyer1994 Well what exactly is the problem? what's the error code. Maybe add some Log statements and see what the value of numTimesPressed is.

Comment: This is the error I receive: "Error:(34, 54) error: local variable buttonPresses is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final".

It is the same error for the array with the strings and for the int variable. It happens before I can test the app on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely need an array of string responses. Afterwards, the first approach I would use is to use a random number generator, and then just link it back to your array. Unfortunately I'm not able to write the code, since I don't know the exact syntax, but in pseudocode:

```
string array[x]={"Hello","Why did you press?",...};//Number of string responses (in this case it's 4)
int random_number;
random_number=RandomNumberGenerator(1,x);//1 and x are the lower and upper bounds
switch (random_number)://If you don't know, switch is basically a simplified if-else system
    case 1:print "Hello";
    .........
```

There are many random number generators online that you can use, depending on the language. Hope this helped!

P.S: Maybe you'll want to fine-tune your responses to make them more natural. For example, you probably want to re-roll your response if you get two of the same one in a row.